# Creating Multiple Associated Records After Creation of Parent Object

Tags: parent-child, nested-forms, after-create

I have an application where users create Appointments, and each Appointment has a set of Skills attached to them through a Appointment_Skills table. There are about 50 or so Skills that I would like to attach to each appointment after creation. Because the appointment form is so large and there are so many things to track, I have the users create an Appointment with a minimal form, then redirect to the edit page where they have access to the whole appointment. I am using nested attributes to update the Appointment and Appointment_Skills in the edit form.

```
Appointment
  has_many :skills, through: :appointment_skills 
  has_many :appointment_skills
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointment_skills
end

AppointmentSkill
  belongs_to :skill
  belongs_to :appointment     
end

Skill

end
```

If I go ahead and create a few AppointmentSkills I can then use my edit form to update their attributes, but I'm not sure how to automatically create them after the parent is created.

I've thought about first getting a count of all the Skills and Ids, then using an after_create callback to create all the AppointmentSkills that would have the Skill Ids and Appointment Ids(of the appointment just created).

Is this possible? Is this a strange way of doing it?

Comment: This does seem a little weird. Your answer will still work, but if you want to always attach the same skills maybe you should figure something else out, instead of creating so many records for each appointment. For example you could have skill_groups. Create a skill group that could be a default group with the necessary skills attached and then assign the skill group to each apointment. If the user needs to change something you can then figure out another workflow for that, but in terms of data I think grouping would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing...

```
    after_create :assign_skills 

    def assign_skills
       skills = Skill.all
       skills.each do |skill|
       AppointmentSkill.create(:appointment_id => self.id, :skill_id => skill.id, :position => skill.priority)
    end
end
```